# Tricky hide & show navbar combination

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to JS, therefore, I could use some help with the following problem.

I'm  trying to combine these two solutions:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp

My problem is that when scrolling down and then up again to the top, the navbar remains fixed and goes all the way up. Then, when scrolling down a bit, it jumps down.

Also, the sliding transition effect doesn't work when the navbar disappears. It should have the same transition as when it appears on scrolling up.

It might sound uneasy to understand based on what I wrote here, but checking out the snippet will help a lot, I promise - just scroll up and down a couple of times! :)

Here's how I was trying to solve it:

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
      window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

      // Get the header
        var header = document.getElementById("navbar");

      // Get the offset position of the navbar
      var sticky = header.offsetTop;

      // Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
      function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          header.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
          header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
      }
      
        /* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
      var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
      window.onscroll = function() {
        var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
        if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
          document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
          header.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-102px";
          header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
        prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
      }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="navbar">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are transitioning padding which is a bad idea. You should use transform: translateY() for that. I would leave the original head where it is and "show" a copy of the header when you are further down the page. You can then check if offsetTop of the original header and the copy match and hide the copy.

Comment: So, do you want to see the navigation bar when scrolling or not? Because those are two different examples. One of them hides and one of them sticks, kind of opposites imo.

Comment: @GifCo that's actually a good idea, I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @Bedir I created an animation to show what I want to achieve: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWPEJKtHZsI-ZBvHrDSCzRsJiZ4yRwh2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches

    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      }
      else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }  
  }

  else {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          header.classList.add("sticky");
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-58px";
        if (window.pageYOffset < sticky) {
          header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would say put both of those functions into the same event and then make sure you don't have conflicting conditions. Try combining the ifs also:

```
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
            header.classList.add("sticky");
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-102px";
        if (window.pageYOffset < sticky) {
            header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes more sense, but still not quite what I want.
Your solution results in this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I1-hH197NdJ8W21xJIRGUkTYklxEWc-d/view?usp=sharing

But I'd like to get something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWPEJKtHZsI-ZBvHrDSCzRsJiZ4yRwh2/view?usp=sharing